# How do I battle with my Pokemon Gold/Silver Pokemon on Pokemon Stadium 2?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal, pokemon-stadium-2

My friend and I have been playing Pokemon Gold and Silver versions on our Gameboy colors, and we thought it would be fun to battle on the big screen using Pokemon Stadium 2. So we got a Transfer Pak and plugged one of our games in and were a bit disappointed by the minimalist layout of the transfer process.

We managed to transfer some Pokemon to the storage box on Stadium, but when we went to do a Free Battle and set the rules to 'Everything Goes' we couldn't find our transferred Pokemon. They didn't show up in the Rental Menu, unsurprisingly, but the only other menus were Registered and another one that contained the party of the Gold Version that was still connected. Connecting two isn't an option because we only have one Transfer Pak.

Do we need to put our Pokemon somewhere other than the storage box? Do we need to get a second Transfer Pak and connect both games at the same time and battle with our in-game parties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here's what I've managed to find out on my own:

1- With the Transfer Pak connected, there is another section added to the Pokemon Selection screen when you are preparing a Free Battle, which allows you to enter and register a team from your Gameboy Color game (it grants instant access to every legal option in your party and all of your boxes).

2- As mentioned above, you can register a team from your Gameboy Color game. This allows you to plug in your game, register your team, turn the N64 off, plug in your friend's game, register their team, and so on, allowing multiple people to play with their Gameboy Color teams without requiring multiple Transfer Paks at once. However, from what I can tell, you can only register teams for games using Preset Rules; if you're using a Custom Ruleset, you cannot register a team.